# Pre-formatted HTML box losing format when retrieved from API

Tags: php, html, json, api, request

I am implementing a recruitement system (Lever) for a client of ours. One of its responsibilities is to list all of the available jobs opportunities inside the client's website.

Based on their API documentation, inside the corresponding PHP file, I wrote the code to retrieve a list of all job listings and then use `json_decode` to parse them, before accessing each field seperately. For example, if I want to retrieve the job title for a single job opportunity, I use `$jr['data'][$x]['text']` inside a for loop, where `$jr` stands for the decoded response and `$x` stands for the current for loop item.

With all that being said, Lever provides a description box when you create a job listing, which allows for simple html formatting and styling (bold, underline, ul, etc.). The problem is, in the process of retrieving and decoding the data inside the actual website, **the html formatting is gone**, meaning for example if the job listing contains a list with the job's requirements, I am not able to see it as a list, rather just joined text. Same goes for any bold or underline formatting.

Any ideas?

**EDIT: Here's the code**

*For the GET Request:*

```
    $url = "https://api.lever.co/v1/postings";
    
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Basic apikeyherebutIhidit",
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    
    $jr = json_decode($resp, true);
    $jrlen = count($jr['data']);
```

*For retrieving the job data (sample):*

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if($category->slug == "cruise") {
        $output .= '<div id="cruise" class="tab-pane fade in active">';
            $output .='<div class="job-department">' . '<div class="panel-group accordion-style2 jobs-accordion">';
                for ($x = 0; $x <= ($jrlen - 1); $x++) { 
                    if ($jr['data'][$x]['categories']['department'] === 'PAX-Cruise Ships') { 
                        $output .=
                            '<div class="panel panel-default text-left">'.
                                '<div class="panel-heading">'.
                                    '<a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-1" href="#accordion-one-link-'.$jr['data'][$x]['id'] .'">'.
                                        '<div class="panel-title">'.
                                            '<span class="text-dark-gray-2 accordion-title">'. $jr['data'][$x]['text'] .'</span>'.
                                            '<i class="vc_tta-controls-icon vc_tta-controls-icon-chevron"></i>'.
                                        '</div>'.
                                    '</a>'.
                                '</div>'.
                                '<div id="accordion-one-link-'.$jr['data'][$x]['id'] .'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'.
                                    '<div class="panel-body">'.
                                    '<div class="job-description">' . $jr['data'][$x]['content']['description'] . '</div>' . 
                                    '<br>' . 
                                    '<input style="width:20px;" class="gdpr_checkbox" type="checkbox" id="gdpr_checkbox_'.$jr['data'][$x]['id'].'" value="gdpr checked"><label for="gdpr_checkbox_'.$jr['data'][$x]['id'].'" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:15px;"> Please confirm that you have read and understood the <a style="color:#f5b14b;text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank" href="https://www.columbia-shipmanagement.com/general-privacy-notice/">General Privacy Notice</a> by checking the box.</label><br>' . 
                                    '<a id="apply_button_'.$jr['data'][$x]['id'].'" class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-lg vc_btn3-shape-square vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-color-orange job-apply-button" type="submit" target="_blank" href="' . $jr['data'][$x]['urls']['apply'] . '" target="_blank" style="pointer-events: none;cursor: default;background-color:grey; border-color:grey;">Apply</a>' . 
                            '</div></div></div>';
                    }
                }
        $output .= '</div></div></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: json_decode doesn't remove any formatting. it means, logically, they don't send any formatting

Comment: Show your code. Do is formatting in database, after retrieving info from database, sent via Ajax request. Maybe someone strips tags as sanitise process (XSS prevention)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation, https://hire.lever.co/developer/documentation#retrieve-a-single-posting, it becomes apparent real quick from the example given there, that they return a field `description`, which has any HTML stripped out - but that there is also a field `descriptionHtml`:

```
"content": {
  "description": "The Infrastructure Engineer will act as...\\nSuperman.",
  "descriptionHtml": "<div>The <u><b>Infrastructure Engineer</b></u> will act as...</div><div>Superman.</div>",
```

Comment: Oh my God I can't believe I missed that when it was right in front of me. Thank you so much!